# debug assertion expression stream!=null every time i use fopen

Tags: c

I'm actually having problems with not one but 2 to 3 programs using files and  their commands like fopen, fscanf, while(strcmp(input,"E")!=0).Atleast, I think that is the problem. All these programs show the same error that is  debug assertion failed! Expression (stream!=null).I tried everything but nothing seems to work pls help. I cant understand what to do. Pls reply as soon as possible.This is one of the programs:

```
    # include <stdio.h> 
    # include <conio.h> 
    # include <string.h> 
    # include <stdlib.h>
    void main() 
    { char add[6],length[10],input[10],binary[12],bitmask[12],relocbit; 
      int start,inp,len,i,address,opcode,addr,actualadd; 
      FILE *fp1=fopen("relinput.dat","r"); 
      FILE *fp2=fopen("reloutput.dat","w");
      system("cls");
      printf("Enter the actual starting address : "); 
      scanf("%d",&start); 
      fscanf(fp1,"%s",input); 
      while(strcmp(input,"E")!=0) 
      { if(strcmp(input,"H")==0) 
         { fscanf(fp1,"%s",add); 
           fscanf(fp1,"%s",length);
           fscanf(fp1,"%s",input); 
          } 
        if(strcmp(input,"T")==0) 
         { fscanf(fp1,"%d",&address);  
           fscanf(fp1,"%s",bitmask);
           address+=start;
           len=strlen(bitmask); 
           for(i=0;i<len;i++)
             { fscanf(fp1,"%d",&opcode); 
               fscanf(fp1,"%d",&addr); 
               relocbit=bitmask[i];
               if(relocbit=='0') 
                   actualadd=addr;
               else 
                   actualadd=addr+start; 
               fprintf(fp2,"%d\t%d%d\n",address,opcode,actualadd);
                   address+=3; 
             }
           fscanf(fp1,"%s",input); 
         }
        } 
        fclose(fp1); 
        fclose(fp2); 
        printf("FINISHED");
         getch(); 
         }
```

Comment: Add error checking to the program. It's almost impossible to debug (or even use) a program with no error checking. For example, after each call to `fopen`, check the returned value for `NULL`. Check the return values of `scanf` and `fscanf` too.

Comment: Please format your code .

Answer (score 0):

You need to do error checking on your fopen procedures and in general. This error is most likely due to a fscanf or fopen returning an unexpected value that you didn't catch.

More useful tips:

- Debug with breakpoints if your IDE allows you to
- Format your code to be more in line and easily readable
- Comment on Functions to make clear what they do, for future readers or your future self.